# change the order of the Expasiontile list by dragging them

Tags: flutter, dart, drag-and-drop, position, draggable

I have a list of objects created by a **ListView.builder**.
this **ListView** returns an **ExpasionTile** for each object in the builder iteration. my purpose is how I can drag an **ExpasionTile** to another position within the list and that through this action the position of the object within the list is changed to its new position and then perform a **setState** and the change is displayed within the **ListView**.

Does anyone know how this could be made possible?

this is what i have right now.

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> articulosSeleccionados = [];

  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Container(
          constraints:
              BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: max(350, 550)),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black45, width: 2),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: articulosSeleccionados.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                     return _articuloSeleccionado(index);
                  },
              ),
           ),
       ),
   );

  Widget _articuloSeleccionado(int index) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
         child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                articulosSeleccionados.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back))),
     const SizedBox(width: 10),
     Expanded(
       flex: 10,
       child: Container(
         margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
         child: ClipRRect(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
           child: ExpansionTile(
             backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[50],
             collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[50],
             textColor: Colors.black,
             title: Text(articulosSeleccionados[index]['nombre']),
             children: [
               Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                 child: Text(articulosSeleccionados[index]['contenido']),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ],
 );
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html

Comment: Refer this blog https://mobikul.com/drag-and-drop-listview-feature-in-flutter/

Comment: You can go for  `ReorderableListView` but it will overlap on trailing and expand state